# Adding Windows Phone 8 SDK on PreInstalled Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have Visual Studio 2012 Installed previously, now I want to add the Windows Phone 8.0SDK to my visual studio 2012.

When I head on to the msdn website to get the sdk, the installer installs SDK and Visual Studio 2012 Express.

I just want the SDK on VS2012. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest Windows Phone SDK should notice that you already have VS2012 and only add the required bits.

> The Windows Phone SDK provides a stand-alone Visual Studio Express
>   2012 edition for Windows Phone **or works as an add-in to Visual
>   Studio 2012 Professional, Premium or Ultimate editions.**

Download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Comment: So I have uninstalled my VS2012 Ultimate and Installed Express2012(with Phone SDK). Now in the new project window there are options only for creating a new project for Windows Phone. How to create general Visual C#(Windows) applications and ASP.NET(Web) in this installation ??

Comment: There are of course no such options, as they are only available in the full versions of Visual Studio. As Olivier pointed out, if you just had ran the SDK installer, it would have installed the SDK into VS2012 Ultimate without any problems.

Comment: Okay, I installed the SDK that was provided in the answer above.I got the phone development. Now how can I get to develop the native windows application in this Visual Studio ?

Comment: You shouldn't have uninstalled the VS2012 Ultimate! As I said in my answser, the WP8 SDK works as an add-in to VS2012. VS2012 is still required for other project types.

Comment: I had VS2012 full installed, then I installed the Winphone8SDK and it also installed the express vs2012. Also, it didn't set up the full vs2012 but only the express vs2012 to work with wp8